# How to correctly simulate a create/update time span operation on dynamics CRM in a Parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, mocking, dynamics-crm

I need to simulate the time that it takes to make a create/update operations to CRM without actually create/update records inside the CRM.

I was looking for a library or some advise on how to do it efficiently.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
logger.Info("Started creation of {0} registers", bulkQueries.Count);

Parallel.ForEach(bulkQueries, element =>
{                       
    if (element.Key)
    {
       service.Update(element.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        service.Create(element.Value);
    }
});
stopwatch.Stop();
logger.Info("Done creating. Total time: {1} secondi", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

What I expect is to have a time that could be very close to the time that an actual update/create take, and report it in the log.

I know that each operation could take different time one from each other, but I don't need a perfect fake copy of the time each operation take, just an average time.

Comment: Is executing real CRUD operations against a test system not an option?

Comment: At last we had to use a test system yes. 
Thanks